# How to set selected item of Spinner by value in JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, android-spinner

I have spinner value based on JSON data :

this is the JSON for spinner value

```
{
    "taxonomy":{
        "City":[
            {
                "city_id":12,
                "name":"Jakarta"

            },
            {
                "city_id":13,
                "name":"Jakarta"
            }
        ]
    } 
}
```

and have JSON User

```
{
    "taxonomy":{
        "User":[
            {
                "ID":112,
                "name":"Ray",
                "city":12

            },
            {
                "ID":113,
                "name":"Tiara",
                "city":12
            }
        ]
    } 
}
```

i already parsing json data in spinner

```
for (int i=0; i<data_city.length();i++){
    JSONObject listcity = data_city.getJSONObject(i);
    Spin_city modelcity = new Spin_kecamatandesa(
        listkec.getInt("city_id"),
        listkec.getString("name")
    );

    Str_array_kec.add(modelcity);
}

SpinnAdapter adapterspin = new SpinnAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Str_array_kec);
spn_edt_kec.setAdapter(adapterspin);
```

My question is, how to set selected item based on JSON user (like city_id equals city) ?

Comment: post your code you have tried already.

Comment: @JakirHossain i have tried already parsing JSON into spinner, but i want to show value based on json user

Comment: You should parse 2 JSON file `City` and `User` Then make a condition like if the user `city` match with City `city_id` then add the id to the `Str_array_kec` list and then add the list to the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the index number of your desired city when you are adding cities in the ArrayList named

> Str_array_kec

Then make the spinner be selected to that item by calling '.setSelection()' function as below:

```
    spn_edt_kec.setSelection(yourDesiredCityIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
// declear a variable named position
int position = -1; 

for (int i=0; i<data_city.length();i++){
    JSONObject listcity = data_city.getJSONObject(i);
    Spin_city modelcity = new Spin_kecamatandesa(
        listkec.getInt("city_id"),
        listkec.getString("name")
    );

    // check city_id is matching or not
    if(listcity.getInt("city_id") == user_city_id){ // here user_city_id is variable whice is assigned when parse user data iterated.
       position = i; // assign matching index to position
    }

    Str_array_kec.add(modelcity);
}

SpinnAdapter adapterspin = new SpinnAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Str_array_kec);
spn_edt_kec.setAdapter(adapterspin);

spn_edt_kec.setSelection(position); // set selected position to  your spinner.
```